# How pass Google access token when POSTing xml

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

First off, I know how to do a typical POST to Google with an access token such as

```
$.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
            refresh_token: localStorage.refresh_token,
            client_id: my_client_id,
            grant_type: 'refresh_token'
        }).done(...}).fail(...});
```

However, now I'm trying to insert a row into a Google spreadsheet.  There are two scenarios here.

1. User clicks 'Log in with Google' and authenticates with Google credentials.  My app then sends a POST request to insert a row into a spreadsheet on their Google Drive. This currently works no problem (i.e. the row IS inserted into the spreadsheet).
2. Instead of having the user authenticate, I obtain an access token for their account using a refresh token stored on a server.  I then execute the exact same POST request as in (1) but it fails silently.

So it seems as if the first scenario is doing some configuration behind the scenes that I am not replicating in (2).  The documentation on the SpreadSheet API said I need to set an authorization header in order to submit this row to the spreadsheet.  I don't know how to do that (I wish the docs gave an example there), but it looks like I can manually set headers using the `beforeSend` setting in jQuery's `ajax` method.  To submit to the spreadsheet the `contentType` of the request must be `application/atom+xml` which means I need to use `$.ajax()` instead of the easier `$.post()` (I think).

To be clear, everything works great when I go through the official login process to obtain an access token (which I currently don't use in the request).  But it does not work in the second scenario.

I traced a similar POST request using Postman and looked at the headers and cookies to see if there was any authorization header, but I didn't see it.  I've looked at a lot of information over a day now and haven't been able to figure out what exactly I need to do.

The request is made from a PhoneGap Android app if that matters.

How can I set a header to the correct credentials?

Here's my code:

```
function postRowFromDatabaseToGoogleSpreadsheet(row) {
var spreadsheetApiUrl = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/myspreadsheet-key/1/private/full";

var xml = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' " +
        "xmlns:gsx='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended'>" +
        "<gsx:{0}>{1}</gsx:{0}>".format("id", row.id) +
        "<gsx:{0}>{1}</gsx:{0}>".format("coverage", row.coverage) +
        "<gsx:{0}>{1}</gsx:{0}>".format("date", row.date) +
        "<gsx:{0}>{1}</gsx:{0}>".format("time", row.time) +
        "<gsx:{0}>{1}</gsx:{0}>".format("comments", row.comments) +
        "<gsx:{0}>{1}</gsx:{0}>".format("kwhr", row.kwhr) +
        "<gsx:{0}>{1}</gsx:{0}>".format("mlwater", row.mlwater) +
        "<gsx:{0}>{1}</gsx:{0}>".format("tabletid", row.tabletid) +
        "</entry>";

console.log("Submitting to URI: " + spreadsheetApiUrl);
console.log("Xml to submit: \n" + xml);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //headers: 
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        console.log("beforeSend");
        console.log(xhr);

        xhr.done(function() {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log("xhr failed...");
        });
    },
    url: spreadsheetApiUrl,
    data: xml,
    contentType: "application/atom+xml",
    crossDomain: true 
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log("post succeeded");
    if (response == null) {
        console.log("response was null");
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
}).fail(function(error) {
    console.log("post failed");
    console.log(error);
}).always(function() {
    console.log("post completed");
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that you can either pass the token in the url or as a header.

To pass in the url, add a parameter `access_token={Your token here}` to the url.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.access_token
    },
    url: url,
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json"
})
.done(function(response) {
   // snip
})
.fail(function(error) {
    //snip
})
```